# Vulkan - Creating multiple pipeline caches from a merged one

Tags: vulkan

If I understand correctly, vkMergePipelineCaches is useful because it allows us to merge caches created from multiple threads into a single one, and then save that on disk.

However, I fail to see how to create these multiple caches once the application is restarted. All I have on disk is the merged cache, so do I need to point to that same big cache on each vkCreatePipelineCache call (one per thread)?

If I'm supposed to save each cache separately, then what is the purpose of vkMergePipelineCaches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> All I have on disk is the merged cache, so do I need to point to that same big cache on each vkCreatePipelineCache call (one per thread)?

You don't need one cache per thread.  The [specification](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.0.37.0/linux/vkspec.chunked/ch02s05.html) says

> Many object types are immutable, meaning the objects cannot change once they have been created. These types of objects never need external synchronization, except that they must not be destroyed while they are in use on another thread. In certain special cases, mutable object parameters are internally synchronized such that they do not require external synchronization. One example of this is the use of a `VkPipelineCache` in `vkCreateGraphicsPipelines` and `vkCreateComputePipelines`, where external synchronization around such a heavyweight command would be impractical.

Read as: *You can load a single massive cache at startup and then let multiple threads use it during pipeline creation without worrying about synchronization issues*

> If I'm supposed to save each cache separately ...

You're not.

> ... then what is the purpose of `vkMergePipelineCaches`?

`vkMergePipelineCaches` allows for a programming style where you might lazily create a pipeline cache on demand when you don't already have one, and then later allow you to merge multiple such caches into a single cache to persist.  Subsequent runs wouldn't need to create the lazy caches because they'd be able to use the loaded one.  It's not necessarily that couldn't always have a single shared cache across threads, but it might not be convenient in every case, particularly when porting from older APIs

Comment: I see! I guess I got confused by the Vulkan Programming Guide book, which mentions creating one cache per thread could give a speed boost (page 185 if you have it). I think I just misunderstood that paragraph though.

Comment: @jesta You can do that. But You don't have to. Driver needs to synchronize internally access to a single cache object. But You might as well create multiple caches, one per thread, to avoid this synchronization. And this might give some performance boost though doesn't have to. Choose what fits You best.

Comment: @Ekzuzy: "*But You might as well create multiple caches, one per thread, to avoid this synchronization.*" But it doesn't actually avoid the use of mutexes, since the implementation doesn't know if you're sharing a cache or not. It merely avoids one thread having to wait on a mutex to become available. Also, the multi-thread approach means that you're wasting time by not *sharing data*, which is the whole point of using a cache.

Comment: @NicolBolas Cache is not shared only at the very first execution of the application. During the following executions, cache data is loaded from the disk and is shared across threads. As for waiting on mutexes... avoiding this wait might speed things a bit. Though this boost may be not noticeable.